# How can I read a byte array in Jmeter from a database?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a MySQL database and am trying to get this byte array using JDBC Request.
I am saving the result in a variable and then in a BeanShell encoding this result in a string and sending it through an HTTP POST:

BeanShell:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64;

String source = vars.get("storedToken_1"); 
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(source.getBytes()); 
String encoded = new String(encodedBytes); 
String code = URLEncoder.encode(encoded, "UTF-8");
vars.put("reset_pass_token", code);
```

The thing is that this **storedToken** I'm getting from the db is coming corrupted so I'm not being able to authenticate the test.

Is there any other way I can retrieve this byte array value from the database and store it in a variable so I can send it in a POST?

Comment: How are you storing the byte array `storedToken_1` into vars? Looks like you're storing it as a string and then fetching it as a string - which in itself is not guaranteed to conserve the byte array properly. Can you maybe base64 encode the array _before_ storing it as a jmeter var?

Comment: @RaGe I'm fetching it from MySQL database, using a JDBC Request and a SQL `SELECT` statement. I suppose it's being stored as a string, but I don't know how I could encode it before storing...

Comment: Using @DmitriT 's answer below, I would try: `String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String((byte[]) vars.getObject("storedToken_1"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable comes as byte array, you need to handle it a little bit differently in Beanshell using [vars.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String)) method, like:

```
String source = new String(vars.getObject("storedToken_1"));
```

Also the way you extract the variable may matter, JMeter won't "corrupt" the data, it might be the case that you misuse JDBC Test Element. See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for available options listed and if it doesn't help - update your question with screenshot or detailed description of your JDBC element configuration.

Comment: If the SQL statement fetches binary data, is it stored into Variables as an object and not a string?

Comment: I don't know what "Variables" you're talking about. If "Result Variable Name" is being used - it has Java type which matches SQL type. For MySQL blob - it'll be byte array. Have you got a chance to read the referenced article prior to asking?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about "Variable names" and "Result Variable Name", The values in the hashmap for the examples in the articles are all strings - but that could be because the queried table contains just strings. You did answer my question though, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @DmitriT . The answer was in your article. I just used the Iterator and inside the iteration I encoded to Base64 and it worked like a charm.